# Brownie contract Interface not working on mainnet-fork

Tags: transactions, brownie, interfaces, forks

I'm following Patric Collins youtube video and trying to deposit wETH in the wETH contract using an interface and working using a fork of mainnet. I am trying to deposit eth in the next contract.
https://etherscan.io/token/0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2
I am using the next interface.
https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/aave_brownie_py/blob/main/interfaces/WethInterface.sol
But when doing it I get the following error.

```
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "brownie/network/contract.py", line 622, in __call__
    return Contract.from_abi(self._name, address, self.abi, owner)
  File "brownie/network/contract.py", line 941, in from_abi
    _DeployedContractBase.__init__(self, address, owner, None)
  File "brownie/network/contract.py", line 686, in __init__
    raise ContractNotFound(f"No contract deployed at {address}")
```

I have tried debugging using brownie console hardcoding adresses to isolate the problem.
Here you have an screenshoot of the instructions and the faillure itself.

[image: error]

I have used this fork before and i have face no issues, also i have done this test using kovan testnet and not issues too.

Here is my fork configuration
[image: network]

Answer (score 0):

The Weth address in get_weth.py should be different from the address cited in your error. Specifically the lines in 'get_weth.py' in question are;

```
weth_address = '0xd0a1e359811322d97991e03f863a0c30c2cf029c'
weth = interface.IWeth(weth_address)
```

.... The code you used to produce this error rather than the error message would be helpful if this does not do the trick.